# Python error when installing pygame using Windows

Tags: python, module, pygame, python-3.6, egg

I am new to this Forum and I wanted to ask you:
I am trying to install pygame and other modules for python, some work, but some don't!
For example we'll take pygame:
1. my setuptools are fully upgraded
2. I use python 3.6.0 (python --version)
3. When i write: `pip install pygame`, this Output Comes:

```
C:\Windows\system32>pip install pygame
```

Collecting pygame
  Using cached pygame-1.9.2.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:

```
WARNING, No "Setup" File Exists, Running "config.py"
Using WINDOWS configuration...

Path for SDL not found.
Too bad that is a requirement! Hand-fix the "Setup"
Path for FONT not found.
Path for IMAGE not found.
Path for MIXER not found.
Path for PNG not found.
Path for JPEG not found.
Path for PORTMIDI not found.
Path for COPYLIB_tiff not found.
Path for COPYLIB_z not found.
Path for COPYLIB_vorbis not found.
Path for COPYLIB_ogg not found.

If you get compiler errors during install, doublecheck
the compiler flags in the "Setup" file.


Continuing With "setup.py"
Error with the "Setup" file,
perhaps make a clean copy from "Setup.in".
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\stein\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-ln36l5el\pygame\setup.py", line 165, in <module>
    extensions = read_setup_file('Setup')
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\distutils\extension.py", line 171, in read_setup_file
    line = expand_makefile_vars(line, vars)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\distutils\sysconfig.py", line 410, in expand_makefile_vars
    s = s[0:beg] + vars.get(m.group(1)) + s[end:]
TypeError: must be str, not NoneType

----------------------------------------
```

And the error:

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\stein\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-ln36l5el\pygame\
```

Yeah I know there are already a lot of questions to this: I tried so much, but nothing worked for me :/
If you have some suggestions, just write a comment, and if you Need some pc info, do that too!
Thank you guys!

PC info:
OS: Windows 10 Home, (NOT LINUX!)
CPU: Intel Core i5-6300HQ CPU 2.30GHz, 
RAM: 8,00GB, 
It is an ACER, 
256GB SSD, 
500GB HDD

Comment: `Path for SDL not found.
Too bad that is a requirement! Hand-fix the "Setup"`: SDL should be installed first. Try that first.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I thought Pygame doesn't yet have support for 3.6?

Comment: No Support for 3.6: see https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pygame and  https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/5i4ado/pygame_192_finally_released_after_more_than_7/

Comment: again someone try to install PyGame with Python 3.6 and have problem. Better install Python 3.5 and wait for awhile.